# Worklight: unable to access server after about 30 mins in background

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

My app is unable to access the server after about 30 minutes in background on Android phone and iPhone.

I know it should be related to the `serverSessionTimeout`. However, I cannot connect to server any more after that occurred, and I tried to invoke `"WL.Client.connect()"`, but it didn't work. I always got request timeout response.

I test my app on local (without DMZ) via `Worklight` Studio embedded server, and it worked fine. Only get this issue on UAT (DMZ) and PROD (DMZ).

```
Project architecture:
 1. DMZ (IBM IMC/LMC)
 2. LAN
 3. Worklight 6.0
 4. Production environment
 5. No Load Balancer and cluster setup

My assumption:
 1. it seems the DMZ kept the credential between DMZ and WL server and didn't refresh it when try to connect WL server again after WL session is timeout.
```

Comment: This "architecture"(?!) does not make any sense. Edit and question and elaborate on your local environment setup and your UAT/PROD setup (How many servers, is there a Load Balancer involved? any special setup otherwise?)

Comment: No Load Balancer and cluster setup. Only through IMC ( you know? :) ) go to access the server in LAN. I suspect it relates to the IMC, such as: the session between IMC and WL server is not refreshed.

Comment: And can you now **edit the question** with this information and a better explanation, like some image/drawing depicting the network topology?

Comment: Also please note that IBM Worklight does not officially support HP IMC so it is unknown how it will function. Perhaps you should contact HP IMC support first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed now.
The root cause is because we sent out two requests to WL server going through IMC at the same time, only the second one shake hands with WL server successfully.

Comment: Glad you've solved it. :-) Please mark as answered when possible.